# jquery add th with specfic data-field

Tags: html, jquery, append

I am trying to add a th to a table with specific data-field attr

My table:

```
 <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="id" title="Perfil" data-formatter="addButton" rowspan="2"></th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;" data-sortable="true" rowspan="2">NOMBRE</th>
                            <th style="vertical-align: middle;"  data-sortable="true" rowspan="2">APELLIDO</th>
                            <th style="vertical-align: middle;"  data-sortable="true" rowspan="2">LEGAJO</th>
                            <th style="vertical-align: middle;" data-sortable="true" rowspan="2">SECTOR</th>
                            <th style="vertical-align: middle;"  data-sortable="true" rowspan="2">EMPRESA</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;" colspan="1" >MAQUINAS</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-field="id" title="Perfil" data-formatter="addButton"></th>
                            <th data-field="nombre" data-sortable="true">NOMBRE</th>
                            <th data-field="apellido" data-sortable="true">APELLIDO</th>
                            <th data-field="legajo" data-sortable="true">LEGAJO</th>
                            <th data-field="sector" data-sortable="true">SECTOR</th>
                            <th data-field="empresa" data-sortable="true">EMPRESA</th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>
```

Then I am doing this when data is loaded via jquery

```
    $("#choferesTable thead tr:eq(0) th:eq(6)").attr('colspan', flotas.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < flotas.length; i++) {
        const alias = flotas[i].nombre;
        $('#choferesTable thead tr:eq(1)').append($(`<th />`, { text: alias }))
        $('#choferesTable thead tr:eq(2)').append($(`<th data-field="ejemplo" />`,{text:""}))

    }
```

And I got this
[image]

my data table row[0] is

```
{ apellido: "Sanchez"
bloqueado: "0"
ejemplo: "SUPERVISOR 2020-12-31"
id: 10002
legajo: "legajo"
nombre: "Carlos"
sector: "sector" }
```

But is not working because is not showing row data correctly. If I edit this directly on html works okey

Comment: Adding a cell to a single row will certainly cause a cell layout mismatch on other rows unless you modify `colspan` values. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue

Comment: If you want to add a data attribute to the element use `'data-text': ""` instead. Note however, that if this data attribute is read by a library on load of the page, adding it to a cell at this stage of the page lifecycle is unlikely to have any effect. To be able to answer your question more effectively we need to see a more complete example of the problem, details of how you use the data attribute, along with the HTML code which works.

Comment: jQuery `:eq` selector is zero based. You have only two rows in head. `:eq(2)` is to target the third row...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have 3

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan tried with $('#choferesTable thead tr:eq(2)').append($(`<th/>`,{'data-field': "ejemplo"})) does not work either

Comment: From the posted HTML, I see only two rows in `thead`...

Comment: When creating a jquery element like you do, do not close the tag. So do `$("<th>")` instead of `$("<th />")`... To set the text, use the `.text()` method... So that would be `$("<th data-field='ejemplo'>").text("your text here")`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have one empty in middle that I use for searchs inputs that I add dyn with jquery

Comment: Ho lol... Haha ok I see. That is super weird anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My META was add new columns dynamically depending on ajax result.

One way to reach this is destroying old table, re-create it and refresh data.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "../ajax/gestion_choferes.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
           tabla_choferes.bootstrapTable('destroy');
            $("#choferesTable thead tr").html('');
            $('#choferesTable tr').remove();
            $('#choferesTable thead').append('<tr><th data-field="id" title="Perfil" data-formatter="addButton" rowspan="2"></th><th style="text-align: center;" data-sortable="true" rowspan="2">NOMBRE</th><th style="vertical-align: middle;"  data-sortable="true" rowspan="2">APELLIDO</th><th style="vertical-align: middle;"  data-sortable="true" rowspan="2">LEGAJO</th><th style="vertical-align: middle;" data-sortable="true" rowspan="2">SECTOR</th><th style="vertical-align: middle;"  data-sortable="true" rowspan="2">EMPRESA</th><th style="text-align: center;" colspan="1" >MAQUINAS</th></tr>');
            $('#choferesTable thead').append('<tr></tr>');
            $('#choferesTable thead').append('<tr><th data-field="id" title="Perfil" data-formatter="addButton"></th><th data-field="nombre" data-sortable="true">NOMBRE</th><th data-field="apellido" data-sortable="true">APELLIDO</th><th data-field="legajo" data-sortable="true">LEGAJO</th><th data-field="sector" data-sortable="true">SECTOR</th><th data-field="empresa" data-sortable="true">EMPRESA</th></tr>');
            addEquiposTable(result.datos.flotas)
            
            $("#choferesTable").bootstrapTable();
            formatTables();
            $("#choferesTable").bootstrapTable('refresh');
        } // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    })
```

[MORE INFO](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1178)

Comment: You should be able to `bootstrapTable('destroy')`, then amend, then re-apply `.bootstrapTable()` without going to the lengths of clearing the tr nodes from the thead.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 oh okey. I'll try. Thanks